# read from file data and than search max value mpi

Tags: arrays, max, mpi

i found this example regarding searching the max value using mpi.

http://inventorsworkshop.wikispaces.com/file/view/max.c

and my data  is in this file:

http://cti.ubm.ro/cpd/colocviu/2014/data.in

Now... the question is how can i adapt the program to find the max from my file? What code section i need to edit? let's say that i can save that file near my code source. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this bit:

```
if (rank == 0) {
/* Initialize Array */
    printf("REM %d \n",rem);
    for(i=0;i<800;i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
```

and instead of `for(i=0...` you while need to do something along these lines:

```
FILE* myfile; 

myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r"); 
if ( myfile == NULL ) { 
    printf("Cannot open TEXT file\n");
    return 1; 
}

integer x;
while (1 == fscanf(myfile, "%x", &i)) {
    printf("%d\n",x);
    array[i]=x;
}
```